# Android NDK - CHECK_INTERFACE

Tags: c++, android-ndk

In Android C++ code, I often see `CHECK_INTERFACE`, for example:

```
CHECK_INTERFACE(IDrm, data, reply);
```

I am not C++ developer, I have a little knowledge of C++ only. I tried to find what `CHECK_INTERFACE` means, respectively what this method does. (I suppose that it is a method). I cannot find any declaration of it.

Could you explain it to me, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a C++ macro, it basically checks to see if the interface exists and you have required permission. Definition of the CHECK_INTERFACE macro is:

```
#define CHECK_INTERFACE(interface, data, reply)                         
if (!data.checkInterface(this)) { return PERMISSION_DENIED; }
```

from: http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/native/include/binder/IInterface.h

P.S. data.checkInterface call is defined here:
http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/native/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp

As I said, it's just to make sure interface exists and you have the permission to access it.